# Cannot compile a linux kernel for an ARM board

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, arm, cross-compilation, x86

I am trying to compile a linux kernel (2.6.32.70) for an ARM board (versatilepb), it is my first steps in embedded linux.

At the end of the compilation, two compressed kernel images are generated inside `/arch/x86/boot` and `/arch/i386/boot` directories, and not inside `/arch/arm/boot`. So it looks like that it doesn't compile for an ARM guest.

First, i call `make versatile_defconfig` in order to generate a default configuration file. I also type `make menuconfig` to enable the option `Use the ARM EABI to compile the kernel`. Then i use `make V=1` with root privilege for compilation (it doesn't work without). In my environment, these two variables are defined : `$ARCH=arm` and `$CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-`.

Is it normal to have a lot of questions during the compilation process, even after generating the configuration file ? Questions are about the kernel compression mode, processor family, ... And for this last one, answers seem to be only x86 an similar cpu !

Comment: Get more info  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268884/153195

Comment: My compiler is not gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf, it's arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc generated from ELDK.

Comment: You should not need root privileges, and that may be the source of your problem: files with bad permissions because they were created by root instead of you, causing some file not to be written at some point. Just check out/unpack the kernel in a clean directory and start again, never using the root account.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i know it' bad but i couldn't compile without root privilege. As you can read below, i've solved the problem by unpacking the kernel archive and restarting the compilation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works, it seems that my kernel directory was not so clean, even after a `make clean && make mrproper`.

After restarting from kernel sources extracted from the archive, i can do a `make V=1` without root privilege and there isn't any questions asked. And the directory `/arch/arm/boot` contains an image of the compressed kernel too (zImage).

Comment: Glad you've solved it, but `chown -R yourname:yourname .` residing in kernel directory and then `make distclean` would work for you.

Comment: Root directories permissions seemed to be fine. But of course, maybe some subfolders needed root privilege, i didn't check recursively. And i didn't know the distclean command, thanks.

Comment: No directories or files _inside Linux kernel source tree_ are necessary to have root privileges set in order to successfully compile the kernel. Short: **forget about root when building Linux kernel** at all. Regular user is able to build a functioning kernel. Of course root can compile kernel, why not, but mixing user and root if you're not an experienced Unix user is going to get you into troubles later.